# How can I get a Component to display in another component?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I have to do the following:

Display a List of Hotels
Include the Address and an image of each Hotel
Then Display what rooms are in the hotel
Filter these rooms by capacity

So far I can get the Hotel's Name, Address and Image displaying fine and can filter these based on what rating they have from 1-5, but I have seperated the Rooms into its own Component with a filter based on how many people can fit in a room (1-5)

The Filter displays fine and I can select any number of people, however none of the rooms are showing at all (it should be displaying the Room name, a Description and Capacity) but I cannot get this to display at all

Hotel.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Hotel.css";
import HotelImages from "./HotelImages";
import Rooms from "./Rooms";

const URL = "https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG";

const Hotel = () => {
  const [hotel, setHotel] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    hotels();
  }, []);

  const hotels = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);

    setHotel(await response.json());
  };

  //   filter hotels button displayed by star rating
  const filterHotels = (e) => {
    const starRating = e.target.value;
    const filteredHotels = hotel.filter(
      (hotel) => hotel.starRating === starRating
    );
    setHotel(filteredHotels);
  };

  //   store filteredHotels in state
  const [filteredHotels, setFilteredHotels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredHotels(hotel);
  }, [hotel]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="selection-filter">
        {/* drop down for useState */}
        <label for="filter">Filter by star rating: </label>
        <select onChange={filterHotels}>
          <option value="0">All</option>
          <option value="1">1 Star</option>
          <option value="2">2 Star</option>
          <option value="3">3 Star</option>
          <option value="4">4 Star</option>
          <option value="5">5 Star</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      {hotel.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="list-group-item hotel-area" key={data.id}>
              <div className="hotel-name">{data.name}</div>
              <img
                className="hotel-image"
                src={data.images[0].url}
                alt={data.images[0].alt}
              />
              <div className="hotel-address">{data.address1}</div>
              <div className="hotel-address">{data.address2}</div>
              <div className="star-rating fas fa-star">{data.starRating}</div>
              <div className="rooms">
                <Rooms rooms={data.rooms} />//this is where I want to display the Rooms.js
              </div>
              <button
                click={<HotelImages images={data.images} />}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary view-all-images"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
              >
                View Images
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hotel;
```

Rooms.js

```
    import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "./Hotel.css";

const Rooms = ({ hotelId }) => {
  const URL = `https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/roomRates/OBMNG/${hotelId}`;
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCapacity, setSelectedCapacity] = useState(null);

  // filter rooms by capacity
  const handleCapacityChange = (e) => {
    const capacity = e.target.value;
    setSelectedCapacity(capacity);
  };

  const filteredRooms = useMemo(
    () =>
      rooms.filter((room) => {
        if (!selectedCapacity) return room;
        return (
          parseInt(room?.occupancy?.maxOverall, 10) ===
          parseInt(selectedCapacity, 10)
        );
      }),
    [rooms, selectedCapacity]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {/* filter dropdown by capacity of room */}
      <div className="selection-filter">
        <label for="filter">Filter by capacity: </label>
        <select onChange={handleCapacityChange}>
          <option value="0">All</option>
          <option value="1">1 Person</option>
          <option value="2">2 People</option>
          <option value="3">3 People</option>
          <option value="4">4 People</option>
          <option value="5">5 People</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      {/* map through the rooms and display them */}
      {filteredRooms.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="list-group-item room-area" key={data.id}>
              <div className="room-name">{data.name}</div>
              <div className="room-description">{data.shortDescription}</div>
              <div className="room-capacity">Capacity: {data.occupancy}</div>
              <img
                className="room-image"
                src={data.images[0].url}
                alt={data.images[0].alt}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Rooms;
```

Looking closer in the Console I am getting the following errors as well:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
    at label
    at div
    at div
    at Hotel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163:76)
    at div
    at App
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
validateProperty$1 @ react-dom.development.js:3749
warnUnknownProperties @ react-dom.development.js:3803
validateProperties$2 @ react-dom.development.js:3827
validatePropertiesInDevelopment @ react-dom.development.js:9541
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:9830
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:10950
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:22193
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26596
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26568
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Hotel`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at Hotel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163:76)
    at div
    at App
printWarning @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87
error @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:61
validateExplicitKey @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1078
validateChildKeys @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1105
jsxWithValidation @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1266
Hotel @ Hotel.js:37
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Rooms.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: room.map is not a function
    at Rooms (Rooms.js:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
Rooms @ Rooms.js:37
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Rooms.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: room.map is not a function
    at Rooms (Rooms.js:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
Rooms @ Rooms.js:37
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Rooms> component:

    at Rooms (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:561:74)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Hotel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163:76)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Rooms.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: room.map is not a function
    at Rooms (Rooms.js:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
Rooms @ Rooms.js:37
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rumple-8z0tho

Comment: have you checked the data type of room.capacity & roomCapacity. I believe both are different. One might be number and other might be string. If dataType is the problem, then use == instead of ===

Comment: I've changed that to == and still getting an error:

Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
    at label
    at div
    at div
    at Hotel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163:76)
    at div
    at App

Answer (score 0):

I see this error:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
at label
at div
at div
at Hotel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:163:76)
at div
at App
```

To fix this warning "Invalid DOM property for. Did you mean htmlFor", use the **htmlFor** prop instead of **for** on your label tags.
The **htmlFor** prop is used because **for** is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Also here:

```
 <div className="rooms">
     <Rooms rooms={data.rooms} />//this is where I want to display the Rooms.js
 </div>
```

You are trying to pass the rooms data but no one prop called as **rooms** is expected in the component declaration.

```
// Rooms.js
const Rooms = ({ hotelId }) => {...}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Good point about htmlFor, I've changed those now, I've also changed it to <Rooms hotelId={data.hotelId} /> as hotelId is the prop name its looking for, its still not displaying however

Comment: Well, i saw in the component that you dont fetch the rooms, you create URL with the prop hotelId, but it never get used, you need to fetch them and set with setRooms.

Comment: Like this:

` useEffect(() => {
    hotels();
  }, []);

  const hotels = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    setHotel(await response.json());
  };

Comment: Yes, the same way.

Comment: Still not rendering, I've included a Codesandbox link to show what I mean now

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rumple-8z0tho

Comment: @SCOCB I did some little changes on your codesandbox, seems like its done, please check.